# on the definition of properness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Why is it necessary to demand a proper morphism to be of finite type?

The valuative criterion makes sense without the assumption of being finite type.

Why is it not enough to say a map is proper if it satisfies the valuative criterion??

Comment: What happens for the disjoint union of infinitely many copies of ${\rm Spec}\, k$ mapping down to ${\rm Spec}\, k$?

Comment: @Piotr Achinger valuative criterion is satisfied ...so i want to say it is proper

Comment: If you have a new definition that is useful for solving some math problem, then you should pursue your idea.  However, most consequences of properness that are regularly used in the literature require the morphism to be of finite type.

Comment: Let $f:X\to Y$ be a qcqs morphism. Then $f$ satisfies the existence part of the val crit of properness iff $f$ is universally closed. Moreover, $f$ satisfies the uniqueness part if and only if $f$ is separated. Thus, if $f$ is a quasi-compact separated morphism, then $f$ satisfies the valuative criterion of properness if and only if $f$ is universally closed. So, maybe, you just want to study separated universally closed morphisms?